# Dynamic table in Jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to JQUERY. I am having problem with dialog box.

1) I want to show dynamic HTML table on JQUERY POP.(how to implement plz suggest!)

2) This below Jquery dialog is closing automatically.

```
 $(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

open Dialog

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function createTable() {

            mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "basicTable" });
            var rows = new Number("3");
            var cols = new Number("3");
            var tr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({ class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"].join(' ') }).appendTo(mytable);
                for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    $('<td></td>').text("text1").appendTo(row);
                }

            }
            //console.log("TTTTT:" + mytable.html());
            mytable.appendTo("#dialog");

        }

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                createTable();
            }
        });


        $('#btnclick').click(function () {
            //$("#inputtext").after('<input type="text">');
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");

        });
    });


</script>
```